# TextInputLayout and CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-textinputedittext

I am using TextInputLayout and it works fine, according to the design it should look like this:
[image]

As you can see from the design, it should be filled and have rounded corners, and also the bottom stroke is inside the component just as I expected and wanted.

The way I did this is by wrapping the TextInputLayout inside a CardView - this clipped it as expected.

However, when I set the Error for the TextInputLayout the under line goes outside the CardView!! like this:

[image]

And also, even after I clean the error and it returns to blue, the bottom stroke stays outside the rouded corners of the CardView!

Here is the item as it in the layout:/

```
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView. //This will give the rounded corners for filled TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/email_text_input_wrapper"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      style="@style/Widget.Card.InputWrapper">

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/email_text_input_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:endIconMode="clear_text"
          style="@style/Widget.TextInputLayout.EmailInputLayout"
          android:hint="@string/email_title">

          <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
              style="@style/Widget.TextInputEditText.EmailInputEditText"
              android:theme="@style/Widget.InputEditText.InputEditText"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
              android:paddingEnd="30dp"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Edited:

Here is the style for the CardView and InputTextLayout:

```
<style name="Widget.Card.InputWrapper" parent="">
    <item name="cardElevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">14dp</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.TextInputLayout.EmailInputLayout" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/semi_black</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/general_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gray_placeholder_text</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">@color/error</item>
    <item name="errorIconDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/general_primary</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Form.Title</item>
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Form.Title.Error</item>
    <item name="endIconTint">@null</item>
    <item name="endIconDrawable">@drawable/ic_icons_general_form_erase_content</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">@dimen/components_corner_radius</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">@dimen/components_corner_radius</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">@dimen/components_corner_radius</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">@dimen/components_corner_radius</item>
</style>
```

Any help will be appriciated, and if there are missing details I can add any code examples if required.

Comment: Why do you use card view for this since TextInputLayout can round corners?

Comment: what is  style="@style/Widget.Card.InputWrapper"

Comment: @SlothCoding I've tried to use the TextInputLayout round corners but it didn't clipped the bottom stroke. CardView did the job

Comment: @Muhammedshamshadp I've added the missing style to my question

Comment: try adding paddingbottom in your cardview

Comment: It can't work in this way. When the error text is displayed the indicatorArea is shown under the bottomline and the card can't wrap it with rounded corners.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, Yes, this is correct! I guess it's not so stright forward to implement such design